# How do i insert data into a table with Entity Manager using spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to insert data into my customer table, but i keep getting a null pointer exception.

Here is how I set up my EntityManager variable.

```
@Repository
public class CustomerInsertRepository {

private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;


@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager = 
entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
```

and then i head into my insertWithQuery function, this is where i try to insert data in my customer table

```
@Transactional
public void insertWithQuery(Customer customer)
{
    entityManager.createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO customer "
            + " (first_name last_name, street_address, zip_code, email, city, state) "
            + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")
    .setParameter(1, customer.getFirstName())
    .setParameter(2, customer.getLastName())
    .setParameter(3, customer.getAddress())
    .setParameter(4, customer.getZipcode())
    .setParameter(5, customer.getEmail())
    .setParameter(6, customer.getCity())
    .setParameter(7, customer.getState())
    .executeUpdate();
}
```

Finally, I execute this insertWithQuery function by running a test case.

```
 @Test
 public void nativeQueryTest()
 {
    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer.setFirstName("Bob");
    customer.setLastName("Jones");
    customer.setAddress("123 baker st");
    customer.setZipcode("123545");
    customer.setEmail("example@example.com");
    customer.setCity("New York");
    customer.setState("NY");


    insertWithQuery(customer);
 }
```

By running my test case, my NullPointerException error is right here

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager = 
entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
```

here is my full class

```
@Repository
public class CustomerInsertRepository {

private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;


@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

@Transactional
public void insertWithQuery(Customer customer)
{
    entityManager.createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO customer "
            + " (first_name last_name, street_address, zip_code, email, city, state) "
            + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")
    .setParameter(1, customer.getFirstName())
    .setParameter(2, customer.getLastName())
    .setParameter(3, customer.getAddress())
    .setParameter(4, customer.getZipcode())
    .setParameter(5, customer.getEmail())
    .setParameter(6, customer.getCity())
    .setParameter(7, customer.getState())
    .executeUpdate();
}

@Test
public void nativeQueryTest()
{
    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer.setFirstName("Bob");
    customer.setLastName("Jones");
    customer.setAddress("123 baker st");
    customer.setZipcode("123545");
    customer.setEmail("example@example.com");
    customer.setCity("New York");
    customer.setState("NY");


    insertWithQuery(customer);
}


}
```

I dont really understand how to fix this error. Thanks

Comment: You forgot to initialize your `entityManagerFactory`?

Comment: The entire point of `EntityManager` is that you don't have to write SQL queries, and Spring Data will remove even the need to write JPA queries--just declare `interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long>`, and you're finished.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the method createEntityManager() is static

Try:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager = 
EntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
```

Instaead

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager = 
entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
```

Comment: Just attempted it, `EntityManagerFactory.createEntityManger()` is not static.

Answer (score 0):

First, null-pointer occurs because you have a field `entityManagerFactory` that you never initialize, and thus it has value null, but you call `entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager()` (thus this is `null.createEntityManager()` call) when initializing `entityManager` field.

You could try to put `@Autowired` annotation over `entityManagerFactory` - but, I don't understand why you don't autowire `entityManager` provided by Spring but instead create your own.

Also you seem to have `@PersistenceContext` annotation on `entityManager` - this one is supposed to inject existing `entityManager` in case you're running inside EJB container or use CDI for dependency injection I guess - but you don't, you use `@Repository` annotation which comes from Spring. And you initialize the field yourself. This annotation should definitely be removed (I presume you put it there to inject `entityManager`, but when that didn't work you've added initialization code - the `entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager()`). Or better - replaced with `@Autowire`, and instead the initialization code should be removed.

E.g. just have

```
@Repository
public class CustomerInsertRepository {

@Autowired
private EntityManager entityManager;
...
```